Does teaching a trade/swimming require a Jewish agent to reap the maximum mitzvah
The Gemara describes the father's obligation to circumcise, redeem him, teach him Torah, teach him a trade, teach him swimming.
If the father fails to do so, the obligation falls on the person, and then on the community at large.
Circumcising is well known as a ritual mitzva and the father and his agent (the mohel) have to be Jewish. However, does it make a difference whether the swimming teacher or the trade teacher is Jewish?
I.e. if someone learns his trade from a non-Jew, is it like being circumcised by a non-Jew? Whereas in the case of circumcision, he needs a Hatafat Dam bris, would he need to have a Jew demonstrate the basics of the trade?
Kiddushin 29a:

Baraita: A father is obligated with regard to his son to circumcise
him, and to redeem him if he is a firstborn son who must be redeemed
by payment to a priest, and to teach him Torah, and to marry him to a
woman, and to teach him a trade. And some say: A father is also
obligated to teach his son to swim. Rabbi Yehuda says: Any father who
does not teach his son a trade teaches him banditry"


IIRC, the Mohel doesn't HAVE to be Jewish because the Mitzva is TO BE circumcised, rather than to circumcise. Similarly, if the father does not redeem his firstborn, he redeems himself. So we can learn that the Mitzvah on the boy is to "know to trade" regardless of the teacher.

How do you learn from a Biblical commandment to a mere recommendation?

It's not a recommendation. It's a rabbinic commandment.

I don't think one who doesn't gets flogged. Maybe prescription or advice are better terms for that. Note the difference between levels of commandment: "דְּתָנוּ רַבָּנַן: הָאָב חַיָּיב בִּבְנוֹ לְמוּלוֹ, וְלִפְדוֹתוֹ, וּלְלַמְּדוֹ תּוֹרָה, וּלְהַשִּׂיאוֹ אִשָּׁה, וּלְלַמְּדוֹ אוּמָּנוּת. וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים: אַף לַהֲשִׁיטוֹ בַּמַּיִם."
